# mongodb query and sort by list item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to sort documents by `funnelSteps[0].count`, that is how to sort by the `count` number of the first `funnelSteps`?

Thank you.

```
{
  "funnelSteps" : [{
      "title" : "step1",
      "criteria" : ["1","2"],
      "count" : 305
    }, {
      "title" : "step2",
      "criteria" : ["1","2","3"],
      "count" : 153
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to refer to nested elements in a structure, so you can indeed specify an element by index:

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "funnelSteps.0.count": 1 })
```

Where the sort order of `1` is ascending or `-1` for descending. See [`.sort()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) for more detail.

That is fine for a "known" position of an array element, but if you wanted to sort by something such as the "least" value within "funnelSteps" then you would do something like this using [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$funnelSteps" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "funnelSteps": { "$push": "$funnelSteps" },
        "lowestCount": { "$min": "$funnelSteps.count" } 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "lowestCount": 1 } }
])
```

So in that case you would need to "pull apart" the array in order to get the value you wanted before sorting. But for a known position you can just use the basic arguments to sort as shown.